# "setState hook is not a function" error in one function, but not another one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a little project with the google books API and I have two handlers, `removeBook` and `addToShelf`, that do essentially the same thing: sends a request to my server, which makes a call to google books and returns an updated list, then updates the component state with the new list. The code is nearly identical, but `removeBook` works and `addToShelf` doesn't.

When a book is added, the setState functions return `TypeError: setHaveReadList is not a function` (or `setReadingNowList` or `setToReadList`, whichever method is being called in the switch statement.

Similar questions on SO talk about importing `useState` and making sure that the initial state is the right data type. I know that's not the problem, and if there were more general issues like that then `removeBook` wouldn't work, but it does.

###### Here's MyLibrary, where `useState` is called

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// other imports

const MyLibrary = () => {
  const [toReadList, setToReadList] = useState(null);
  const [readingNowList, setReadingNowList] = useState([]);
  const [haveReadList, setHaveReadList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //initial lists are set here, this all works fine
  }, []);

  return (
      <Container maxWidth="95%">
        <Tabs
          onChange={(index) => {
            setActiveTab(index);
          }}
        >
          <TabList>
            <Tab>To Read</Tab>
            <Tab>Reading Now</Tab>
            <Tab>Have Read</Tab>
          </TabList>
          {!toReadList ? (
            <Container centerContent>
              <Spinner mt={10} size="xl" />
            </Container>
          ) : (
            <TabPanels>
              <TabPanel textAlign="center">
                {toReadList.length === 0 ? (
                  <EmptyShelf />
                ) : (
                  <CardGridShelf
                    books={toReadList}
                    shelfId={2}
                    setToReadList={setToReadList}
                  />
                )}
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel w="100%" h="auto" textAlign="center">
                {readingNowList.length === 0 ? (
                  <EmptyShelf />
                ) : (
                  <CardGridShelf
                    books={readingNowList}
                    shelfId={3}
                    setReadingNowList={setReadingNowList}
                  />
                )}
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel textAlign="center">
                {haveReadList.length === 0 ? (
                  <EmptyShelf />
                ) : (
                  <CardGridShelf
                    books={haveReadList}
                    shelfId={4}
                    setHaveReadList={setHaveReadList}
                  />
                )}
              </TabPanel>
            </TabPanels>
          )}
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
  );
};

export default MyLibrary;
```

###### BookDetailShelf, where `removeBook` and `addToShelf` are:

```
import React from "react";
//other imports

const BookDetailShelf = ({ <-- I know these props are passed correctly
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  bookData,
  shelfId,
  setToReadList,
  setReadingNowList,
  setHaveReadList,
}) => {
  const token = useToken().token;
  const toast = useToast();

  const removeBook = (bookId, shelfId, token) => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/remove-book", {
        params: {
          shelfId: shelfId,
          token: token,
          bookId: bookId,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedBookList = response.data.bookResponse; //<--returns an array
        if (updatedBookList === undefined) {
          updatedBookList = [];
        }
        switch (response.data.shelfResponse) {
          case "2":
            setToReadList(updatedBookList);
            break;
          case "3":
            setReadingNowList(updatedBookList);
            break;
          case "4":
            setHaveReadList(updatedBookList);
            break;
        }
        toast({
          title: "Book removed!",
          status: "success",
          duration: 5000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
        onClose();
      })
  };

  const addToShelf = (bookId, shelfId, token) => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/add-to-shelf", {
        params: {
          bookId: bookId,
          shelfId: shelfId,
          token: token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedBookList = response.data.bookResponse; //<--returns an array
        if (updatedBookList === undefined) {
          updatedBookList = [];
        };
        switch (response.data.shelfResponse) {
          case "2":
            setToReadList(updatedBookList); //<-- these throw the error
            break;
          case "3":
            setReadingNowList(updatedBookList); //<-- these throw the error
            break;
          case "4":
            setHaveReadList(updatedBookList); //<-- these throw the error
            break;
        }
        toast({
          title: "Book added!",
          status: "success",
          duration: 5000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
        onClose();
      })
  };
```

Comment: Where is `BookDetailShelf` used in your code?

Comment: `BookDetailShelf` is a child of `CardGridShelf`

Comment: Well, then it may be that you are not passing down the right props from `CardGridShelf` to `BookDetailShelf ` - check if logging them is fine!

Comment: That's weird... when passed into `CardGridShelf` and `BookDetailShelf`, `setToReadList` logs a function but the others are undefined. Yet, `setToReadList` still throws the same error as the other two when called in the switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in setToReadList and the others. It is not a best practies to pass a setState from Parent to Child directly, you must wrap inside a function in the parent and then pass the function to the child.

```
//Original setState in the parent

const [state,setState]= useState([])

//function that wraps the setstate and can be passed down to child.

handleSetState()=>setState({...})
```

Also I was wondering..axios.get? Maybe axios.put or post when you send an object to server?

Hope for the best,

Mauro

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping the setState functions in another function and passing that down worked.

Comment: My server is just abstracting the API calls to Google, I'm not actually modifying anything directly on the server, so axios.get is all I need to send/receive info