# How to filter product based on checkbox with two components sharing state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I've been scratching my head trying to figure out how to display my subCategory products in my Accordian.jsx component based on this checkbox filter that filters products based on their condition in my Filter.jsx component.

The problem is that subCategoryProducts loads properly when no checkbox isChecked, but as soon as I check "Out Of Box" value to display products with a condition value of "Out Of Box," subCategoryProducts array is empty, when it should be all the products containing the condition value of "Out Of Box" and no products end up being displayed.

filteredProducts in Accordian.jsx console logged is an array of subCategoryProducts, but filteredProducts is an empty array upon checking the Out Of Box checkbox when it should be displaying my subCategoryProduct that does have the "Out Of Box" condition value.

I currently updated my parent component to be :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Filter from './Filter'
import Accordian from './Accordian'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'



const ProductListSubCategory = () => {

  const [productCondition, setProductCondition] = useState([]);
 
  const handleSetProductCondition = (newProductCondition) => {
    setProductCondition(newProductCondition);
  }

 
 
  const {subCategory} = useParams();
  const {mainCategory} = useParams();

  const [subCategoryLink, setSubCategoryLink] = useState([]);
  const [mainCategoryLink, setMainCategoryLink] = useState([]);

  const [subCategoryProducts, setSubCategoryProducts] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/category/${subCategory}`);
        const productIds = res.data.products;
        console.log(productIds);
        const productRequests = productIds.map(productId => axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${productId}`));
        console.log(productRequests)
        const productResponses = await Promise.all(productRequests);
        const products = productResponses.map(response => response.data);
        console.log(products);
        setSubCategoryProducts(products);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.error(error?.response?.data ?? error.message);
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, [subCategory]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSubCategoryById = async () => {
      try {
        const response  = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/category/${subCategory}`)
        setSubCategoryLink(response.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
    fetchSubCategoryById();
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMainCategoryById = async () => {
      try {
        const response  = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/category/main-category/${mainCategory}`)
        setMainCategoryLink(response.data)
        console.log(mainCategoryLink)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
    fetchMainCategoryById();
  },[])


      return (
        <>
        <Box sx={{display:"inline-flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>

           <Filter productCondition={productCondition || []} setProductCondition={handleSetProductCondition} subCategoryProducts={subCategoryProducts}/> 
          <Accordian subCategoryProducts={subCategoryProducts}  productCondition={productCondition || []} subCategoryLink={subCategoryLink} mainCategoryLink={mainCategoryLink}  />
        </Box>
        </>
      )
}

export default ProductListSubCategory
```

I have my Accordian.jsx code :

```
const Accordian = ({subCategoryProducts, subCategoryLink, mainCategoryLink, productCondition} ) => {

const productConditions = subCategoryProducts.map(product => product.condition);
  console.log(productConditions);

  const filteredProducts = productCondition.length
  ? subCategoryProducts.filter(product => productCondition.includes(product.condition))
  : subCategoryProducts;


{filteredProducts.map((product) => (
        <GridItem key={product._id}>
          <Card 
            id={product._id}
            image={product.image}
            title={product.title}
            price={product.price}
            description={product.description}
            location={product.location}
            condition={product.condition}
            category={product.category}
            seller={product.seller}
          />
        </GridItem>
      ))}
```

Here is the Filter.jsx code:

```
const Filter = ({productCondition, setProductCondition, subCategoryProducts, }) => {

  

  const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;

    const newProductCondition = isChecked 
  ? [...(productCondition || []), value]
  : (productCondition || []).filter((condition) => condition !== value);

    setProductCondition(newProductCondition);
   
  };

 <Checkbox
        value="New"
        mr={3}
        isChecked={productCondition.includes('New')}
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
      >
        New
      </Checkbox>
      <Checkbox
        value="Used"
        mr={3}
        isChecked={productCondition.includes('Used')}
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
      >
        Used
      </Checkbox>
      <Checkbox
        value="Out Of Box"
        isChecked={productCondition.includes('Out Of Box')}
        onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
      >
        Out of Box
      </Checkbox>
```

I fetch my SubCategory products using useEffect and everything works until I tried finally coding the filtering of the products.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As your error says, the `selectedConditions` is somehow undefined.

Please consider optional chaining `selectedConditions?.includes('New')`

Comment: That helped clear that error but now I get an error saying : "setSelectedConditions is not a function
    at Object.handleCheckboxChange [as current] (Filter.jsx:69:1)". setSelectedConditions is still console logged as undefined as well whenever the component renders.

Comment: Please check the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732589/13560541) also you're passing a callback inside the setSelectedConditions hook instead of the values.

Comment: I wrapped the setState function and passed it down to child in the parent and the problem still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle and share the link here?

Comment: the previous problems are gone now. The only problem is that when a checkbox isChecked, the products that are supposed to be displayed aren't. I updated the error problem above. Please look. Thank you